# App closes upon using BACKSPACE or SHIFT button in an EditText view

Tags: android

When using the **BACKSPACE** or **SHIFT** of the onscreen keyboard to edit text in `EditText` views, my app closes (didn't have this problem before). It is possible to type in text, but as soon as I use BACKSPACE or SHIFT, the app closes.

Logcat gives the following alerts:

```
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
```

Line 106 of **Handler.java** reads as follows;

```
handleMessage(msg);
```

Line 214 of **Looper.java** reads as follows;

```
if (logSlowDispatch) {
     showSlowLog(slowDispatchThresholdMs, dispatchStart, 
     dispatchEnd, "dispatch", msg);
}
```

What action should I take to remedy this? Here is the full Logcat

```
    2019-09-09 16:46:12.416 13560-13560/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2019-09-09 16:46:12.417 13560-13560/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2019-09-09 16:46:23.608 13560-13560/com.commonsense.android.doorway E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.commonsense.android.doorway, PID: 13560
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method dispatchUnhandledKeyEventPre(Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/KeyEvent;)Z in class Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat' appears in /data/app/com.commonsense.android.doorway-4nmhQXtmyOPwFjuoPHsunQ==/base.apk)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1162)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2529)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:590)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6094)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5949)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5402)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5455)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5421)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5580)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5429)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5637)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5402)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5455)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5421)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5429)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5402)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8467)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:8387)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8340)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:5039)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7094)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

And this is the `build.gradle` file. Android Studio says that mixing versions (like 28.0.0) in the `dependencies` can lead to bugs. Apparently they schould all be the same version. Could this be the problem source?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.commonsense.android.doorway"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:wear:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.4.0'
}
```

When I detach the `EditText` views from their `editText = findViewBy(R.id.editText)`, the error stops. But then of course the `EditText` views have become useless.

Comment: Can you post your complete log here

Comment: May need to see the error log to know what's going on here

Comment: This isn't the right logcat.

Comment: @CommonSense I don't think the error is in `android.os.Handler`, it is likely in your code, please share the full log cat.

Comment: Both Handler.java and Looper.java are too long to post entirely. Which sections should I post?

Comment: Have added the Logcat to the main body of the question

Comment: Is there a longer version of that logcat? It still might be incomplete. What version of the Android SDK does your phone use? When did this start occurring and what did you do to possibly cause this issue? Are you using AndroidX or the former support library?

Comment: No, this is it. The first two lines is the app working fine. The rest of the lines was produced upon using the backspace button.

Comment: Cannot immediately answer your ID questions (give me some time), but must have installed and test run (always on the same phone) the app dozens of times in the past few weeks, without this problem ever occurring. Because I don't have an Intel processor, I cannot use the AVD emulator. So I'm obliged to test run everything on my phone, a 2019 Samsung Galaxy J4+.

Comment: It started occurring out of the blue. I hadn't worked on the page the EditText views are on for days. Have installed/ran the app numerous times since, but admittingly rarely visited the EditText page. So it might be that the error has been in there for a while, but that I just didn't notice (because not entering any EditTexts).

Comment: Where can I check phone's SDK and Android X? Is what is on the phone at all important, as the app is supposed to run on any (fairly recent) android phone?

Comment: Have tested the app on another phone, of another brand (Huawei instead of Samsung), and the problem persists. So the source of the problem is unlikely to be phone-related.

Answer (score 0):

In the `build.gradle` file, I deleted `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'`. Android Studio had warned in uncertain terms (as usual) that putting different versions in the dependencies "might produce some bugs". The said dependency was the first that could be deleted without causing any compile errors. And waddayou know, the backspace/shift bug disappeared immediately...